# Efficient algorithm to find a minimum spanning set for a given vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, matroids

A few days ago a colleague proposed the following problem.

---

Let $W$ be a finite subset of a vector space $V$, and let $v\in\langle W\rangle$ (the linear span of $W$).  Is there an efficient algorithm to find a subset $S$ of $W$, *of minimum size*, such that $v\in\langle S\rangle$?

---

On the one hand, this is "just" linear algebra, so we instinctively expect there to be a good algorithm.  On the other hand, it has a combinatorial flavour that seems a bit like a minimum set cover problem, so perhaps it is hard.  Of course, this is only interesting in the case that $W$ is linearly dependent since there may be multiple minimal subsets of $W$ that span $v$ with different sizes. (By *minimal*, I mean that no proper subset will do.)  Finding a *minimal* subset seems easy; finding a *minimum* subset seems harder, but maybe there is something elementary that we're not noticing.

Comment: Let $n = |W|$, and consider the linear map $k^n \to W$ where $e_i \mapsto w_i$.  The preimage of $\{v\}$ under this linear map is some $(n-m)$-plane, so the question amounts to the following: given a linear subspace of affine space, find a point which has as many coordinates zero as possible.

Answer (score 0):

minimal spanning subset $=$ minimum spanning subset
(All basises of $\langle W\rangle$ has the same number of vectors.)